# Vuejs data filter for json

Tags: vuejs2

Before that, I stored the data directly in the component in "Data ()" as an array of "Technologies" and filtered by type and output in html. It turned out that I had to put in a separate file and add more data to it. And now the filter does not work because of this approach. How to fasten it to this type of data? The structure of the "data.json" file is as follows. I need to filter the array by type and output.

```
[
  {
    "language": "Rus",
    "Technologies":[{
                        label: "Vue Js ",
                        price: 1.3,
                        type:"js"
                    },
                    {
                        label: "CMS WordPress",
                        price: 1.05,
                        type:"CMS"
                    }],
    "Another":[{},{}...],
  }
]
```

What was the structure before and how it worked.

```
export default {
        name: 'testappp',
        data() {
            return {
                Technologies: [
                        {
                            label: "Vue Js ",
                            price: 1.3,
                            type:"js"
                        },
                        {
                            label: "CMS WordPress",
                            price: 1.05,
                            type:"CMS"
                        },
                        {
                            label: "Yii2",
                            price: 1.5,
                            type:"php"

                        },
                        {
                            label: "другой js-фреймворк",
                            price: 1.7,
                            type:"noname"
                        },
                        {
                            label: "React Js ",
                            price: 1.9,
                            type:"js"
                        },
                        {
                            label: "CMS Joomla",
                            price: 1.1,
                            type:"CMS"
                        },
                        {
                            label: "Laravel",
                            price: 1.6,
                            type:"php"
                        },
                        {
                            label: "другой php-фреймворк",
                            price: 1.8,
                            type:"noname"
                        },
                        {
                            label: "Angular",
                            price: 1.6,
                            type:"js"
                        },
                        {
                            label: "CMS OpenCart",
                            price: 1.3,
                            type:"CMS"
                        },
                        {
                            label: "Symfony",
                            price: 1.6,
                            type:"php"
                        },
                        {
                            label: "Другая CMS",
                            price: 1.9,
                            type:"noname"
                        }
                ]

 }        }
```

Filter as looked

```
computed: {            

            filteredItemsJS() {
                return this.Technologies.filter(item => {
                            return item.type.toLowerCase().indexOf("js") > -1
                        })
            },
            filteredItemsNoName() {
                return this.Technologies.filter(item => {
                            return item.type.toLowerCase().indexOf("noname") > -1
                        })
            },
            filteredItemsCMS() {
                return this.Technologies.filter(item => {
                            return item.type.toLowerCase().indexOf("cms") > -1
                        })
            },
            filteredItemsPHP() {
                return this.Technologies.filter(item => {
                            return item.type.toLowerCase().indexOf("php") > -1
                        })
            }
        }
```

Comment: are you using `vue cli`?

Answer (score 0):

Since you have a default export in your code we obviously have a module system in place s you can import a local file into the component as follows:

```
import jsonData from './path/to/file';
```

You can then `JSON.parse` this in the created function (see below as it's the same function) onto your Technologies array.

If you wish to load data.json from a remote server use can the ajax library of your choosing (axios etc) to retrieve the data in the `created` function.

Since the json response you have shown maps directly to your hardcoded array on data you can simply assign the response to data using `this.Technologies`.

I'd recommend initialising data.Technologies as an empty array to prevent any of your existing computed properties from failing.  Since these are reactive, once you have loaded the Technologies array any bindings against the filtering computed properties will be updated automatically.

Something like this...

```
default export {
  name: "",
  data(){
    return {
        Technologies: []
    }
  },
  computed: {....},
  created() {
    ajaxPromiseLib.get(URL_TO_JSON_ENDPOINT).then(data => this.Technologies = data);
  }
}
```